# Homotopy classes of maps from $S^1$ to the Grassmanian $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, grassmannian

We consider that $\text{Vect}_n^{\mathbb{R}}(X)$ denotes the set of isomorphism classes of $n$-dimensional real vector bundles over $X$ - see page 18 of Hatcher's [*Vector Bundles and K-Theory*](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf). Moreover, we let $[X, Y]$ denote the set of homotopy classes of maps $X \to Y$. Take $X = S^1$ and $Y = G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$. If we take $n=1$, then we obtain

$$\operatorname{Vect}_1^{\mathbb{R}}(S^1) \cong [S^1, G_1(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})] \cong [S^1, \mathbb{R}\text{P}^{\infty}] \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{R}\text{P}^{\infty}) \cong H_1(\mathbb{R}\text{P}^{\infty}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2.$$

I'm confused about how to do this for general $n$ however.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you wrote $[S^1, \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}] \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty})$. This is not immediate because the left-hand side denotes the collection of homotopy classes of maps $S^1 \to \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$, while the right-hand side denotes the collection of *base-point preserving* homotopy classes of maps $S^1 \to \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$, which I would denote by $[S^1, \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}]_{\bullet}$.

In general, $[S^1, X]$ is a quotient of $\pi_1(X) = [S^1, X]_{\bullet}$ by an action of $\pi_1(X)$, namely conjugation, so $[S^1, X] \cong \pi_1(X)$ if and only if $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian. In particular, $[S^1, \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}] \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty})$ as $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ is abelian.

Returning to the question at hand, $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ is the classifying space of principal $O(n)$-bundles. So there is a universal $O(n)$-bundle $E_n \to G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ with $E_n$ weakly contractible. In fact, $E_n = V_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ and the associated vector bundle is the tautological bundle $\gamma_n$. The long exact sequence in homotopy applied to the universal $O(n)$-bundle gives

$$\dots \to \pi_1(E_n) \to \pi_1(G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})) \to \pi_0(O(n)) \to \pi_0(E_n) \to \pi_0(\operatorname{Gr}_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})).$$

As $E_n$ is weakly contractible, it is connected and simply connected, so

$$\pi_1(G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})) \cong \pi_0(O(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2.$$

Since $\pi_1(G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ is abelian,

$$\operatorname{Vect}_n^{\mathbb{R}}(S^1) \cong [S^1, G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})] \cong \pi_1(G_n(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2.$$

A different way to compute $\operatorname{Vect}_n(S^1)$ is to use the [clutching construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clutching_construction) in which case we see that

$$\operatorname{Vect}^{\mathbb{R}}_n(S^1) \cong [S^0, O(n)] \cong \pi_0(O(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$$

as before.